# Pass Array of object from angular $http to mvc web api via post method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I try to pass an array of object from angular to mvc webapi via post method but with no success.

This is my client code:

```
    $http({
        url: '/api/messages/graph',
        data: { users: siteService.siteObject.users  },
        method: 'Post'
    })
```

This is my mvc web api controller (Try with `[FromBody]` attribute and without)

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public List<graph_item> graph([FromBody] DaganUser[] users)
    {
     ...
    }
```

In the browser console seems that the data pass to server, But the controller parameter always null

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing object

Convert this

```
public List<graph_item> graph([FromBody] DaganUser[] users)
```

to this

```
public List<graph_item> graph([FromBody] DaganUser users)
```

And `DaganUser` should have the property name `users` as you are passing object with property `users`

Answer (score 0):

Anik Islam Abhi You give me the direction to the solution, and instead of passing

```
 data: { users: siteService.siteObject.users  },
```

I wrote

```
  $http({
                url: '/api/messages/graph',
                data:  siteService.siteObject.users  ,
                method: 'Post'
            })
```

And now it work Thanks